# Why don't I need a constructor for a static inner class?

Tags: java, android, class, object, static

If I have an inner static class, why I don't need a constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *need* a constructor for *any* class in Java.  If you don't define one, a default constructor is provided.  It will be equivalent to this:

```
public MyClass() {
    super();
}
```

(Of course, that default constructor may not "work"; i.e. it may result in compilation errors.  The implicit `super();` means that superclass needs to have a no-args constructor, and that constructor needs to be visible to the subclass.  If these preconditions are not satisfied, you *need* to explicitly declare a constructor that explicitly chains to some other superclass constructor.)

Static inner classes are not different to other kinds of Java class ... in this respect.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a constructor for any class, because if you don't provide one, a public, no-arg constructor that does nothing is implicitly provided. The only time you would need to specify a constructor is if the superclass does not provide a visible no-arg constructor.